# javascript - find nested object key by its value

Tags: javascript, object, key

I'm trying to find key of object which is containing my value.

There is my object:

```
var obj = {}

obj["post1"] = {
    "title":    "title1",
    "subtitle": "subtitle1"
}

obj["post2"] = {
    "title":    "title2",
    "subtitle": "subtitle2"
}
```

And now, I'm trying to get object key of value "title2"

```
function obk (obj, val) {
  const key = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === val);
  return key
}

console.log(obk(obj, "title2"))
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

Desired output:

```
post2
```

Comment: `obj[key].title === val`

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the subkey of the object:

```
 function obk (obj, prop, val) {
   return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key][prop] === val);
 }

 console.log(obk(obj, "title", "title2"));
```

Or you could search all values of the subobject:

```
 function obk (obj, val) {
   return Object.keys(obj).find(key => Object.values( obj[key] ).includes(val)); 
 }

 console.log(obk(obj, "title2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array map:

```js
var obj = {}

obj["post1"] = {
    "title":    "title1",
    "subtitle": "subtitle1"
}

obj["post2"] = {
    "title":    "title2",
    "subtitle": "subtitle2"
}
//console.log(obj);
function obk (obj, val) {
    var result = "";
    Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        if(obj[key].title === val)
            result = key;
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(obk(obj, "title2"));
```

Or use array find to optimize searching function:

```js
var obj = {}

obj["post1"] = {
    "title":    "title1",
    "subtitle": "subtitle1"
}

obj["post2"] = {
    "title":    "title2",
    "subtitle": "subtitle2"
}
//console.log(obj);
function obk (obj, val) {
    result = Object.keys(obj).find(key => {
        if(obj[key].title === val)
            return key;
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(obk(obj, "title1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it, just add `obj[key].title === val` as mentioned by Chris G.

Here's an ES6 one liner that returns an array of all matches.

```js
var obj = {}

obj["post1"] = {
    "title":    "title1",
    "subtitle": "subtitle1"
}

obj["post2"] = {
    "title":    "title2",
    "subtitle": "subtitle2"
}

const filterByTitle = (obj, title) => 
  Object.values(obj).filter(o => o.title === title);

console.log(filterByTitle(obj, 'title1'))
```